# Azure Function publish - "Timed out waiting for SCM to update the Environment Settings"

Tags: azure, azure-functions

I've deployed and published several Function Apps without issues over the last 12 months. However, as of this week, when publishing a Function App using the following PowerShell script:

```
func azure functionapp publish <functionAppName> --java
```

I will receive the following error after a few minutes: "Timed out waiting for SCM to update the Environment Settings"
Similarly, I'm also unable to deploy any Function Apps, using:

```
mvn azure-functions:deploy
```

In the Function App activity log, the following error is logged for both cases:

```
Operation name: Sync Web Apps Function Triggers. 
Status: Failed. 
Error code: BadRequest (HTTP Status Code: 400)
Message: Encountered an error (InternalServerError) from host runtime.
```

So far I've created the Application setting WEBSITE_WEBDEPLOY_USE_SCM (value: true) based on feedback in another topic, which unfortunately hasn't helped. Other than that I've not been able to find much other information on this issue.

Does anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Can you check if you have added any Access Restriction for your Function App.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved this issue myself. The Application Setting `WEBSITE_CONTENTAZUREFILECONNECTIONSTRING` contained an outdated storage account key.